# Issue extracting value with Regex between string and slash

Tags: regex, extract

I have an output which I need to extract a version number from and I have not been successful so far.

Example output

Additionaltext'filename.cba;1.0.0.6963978692876\Additionaltext

I need to extract the version number between filename.cba and the "\".  Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what language you're using, but you'd basically just use something like this: `^.+\..+;(.*)\\.*$` and then extract the group. This is a *VERY* specific regex that matches your example. More examples might help generalize the regex if needed.

Comment: Could you show us your current code?

Comment: Was trying to use this (?s)(?<=filename.cba;=).+?(?=\)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\d.+\d
```

It gives you everything between two digits, since there are no digits in your output other than the version.

If you want to find the version (i.e. digits and dots) between the semi-colon and the slash, try this:

```
(?<=;)[\d\.]+(?=\\)
```

If you want your pattern (with the entire `filename.cba;` lookbehind), try this:

```
(?<=filename\.cba;).+?(?=\\)
```

However, if the second pattern works for you, it is a bit more efficient (95 steps) than the third one (131 steps).

Comment: Sorry but there can be additional digits in the string from which we are extracting.  Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer to also show you how to fix your own pattern. It is a bit less efficient, but you can decide which one.